# Show that the following language is not recursive:

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, undecidability

$L = \{w \mid M_w \text{exists and it accepts a word } x_1 = 0x \text{ if and only if it accepts } x_2 = 1x\}$ ($x \in \Sigma^*$, so $x_1$ is starting with a 0 and $x_2$ is obtained from $x_1$ by changing the first 0 to a 1).

Comment: Honestly I think I need to reduce it to another language that's undecidable but I'm stuck on which language it might be.

Comment: The language $H_\varepsilon = \{w = \langle M_w \rangle \mid M_w(\varepsilon) \neq \bot\}$ works with a Turing-reduction.
Hint: Construct from your input $w$ a Turing machine $M_w^\ast$ that computes a function which does not depend completely on $w$, i.e. the output $M_w^\ast(x)$ only depends on $x$, not on $w$ for _some_ $x$.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

We say a language $L$ is *good* if "$0x\in L$ if and only if $1x\in L$". Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of all good languages. Then you are trying to determine whether the language recognized by a given TM belongs to $\mathcal{L}$. Since $\mathcal{L}$ is non-trivial, according to [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Introduction), this is undecidable.

If you want a proof without Rice's theorem, you can take a look at [the proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Formal_proof) of Rice's theorem and try to write a proof for this specific problem. This is not hard.